# The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for App1.Android.dll (v9.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v8.1)

Tags: android, xamarin

My project was 8.1 and working then i could not show the Emulator enymore.

And this is one of the error i got.

> The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for App1.Android.dll (v9.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v8.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.

I change the project to

[image]

and then i even change the Android Manifest to

[image]

When i then run

[image]

or the

[image]

Still dont work.

I see alot of people have this problem but no solution that works
I would like to be able to see the emulator and run on 8.1 again.
But if i even can get the emulator to work again  becous its just black or be just a dummy that dont start the application.

IN the design view i can see the views.

Comment: Does your `.csproj` have the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` of 9.0, and it's the only project in the solution?

Comment: Cause of your problem:

There is a referce of project App1.Android which targets (v9.0).

Solution:

Set the compile version, Minimum version, Target version to v9.0 and run it on a simulator of v9.0.

Comment: lemontree This dont help at all sorry

Comment: @Jon Douglas 
It dosent change anything to
Minimum 7.0
Maximum 9.0 
I have 2 other projects in the solution but one is Asp.net website and one is webservice